# Javascript RegExp to search for pipe(|) or dash(-) with trailing variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to search through string title values that will always have a trailing dash or pipe and a specific variable at the end, for example: **"Is love real? - Example"**, *or*  **"Top 10 Ways To Not Be Lazy at Work | Another Example"**

My final goal is to simply call the replace function if any RegExp match returns positive in the string(where the exampleVariable must be supplied) and strip it out entirely from and including the pipe or dash like so:

```
brandNameTitle.replace((\|)?(\-)?\s`${exampleVariable}`, '');
```

The final result would be something like, **Is love real?** or **Top 10 Ways To Not Be Lazy at Work**

I know my regex is currently wrong, and I've tried other variations of different regexs but my syntax is wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @anubhava that doesn't seem to work for me. It doesn't strip out anything, just returns the same string.

Comment: @anubhava replied to your comment.

Comment: Why not split by dash or pipe and get the first element of the resulting array? That’s a gazillion times faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex to search:

```
`\\s*[|-]\\s*${exampleVariable}$`
```

Note use of double slash in regex string.

**Code:**

```js
function replTitle(brandNameTitle, exampleVariable) {
  let re = new RegExp(`\\s*[|-]\\s*` + exampleVariable.replace(/\.com$/, ""));
  return brandNameTitle.replace(re, "");
}

console.log(replTitle(`Is love real? - Example`, `Example.com`))

console.log(replTitle(`Top 10 Ways To Not Be Lazy at Work | Another Example`, 
   `Another Example`))
```

Comment: That gets me very close! However, I just found a small edge-case where sometimes the exampleVariable may have a trailing ".com" at the end, so for ex: "exampleVariable.com" instead of the just the string exampleVariable. Is there a way we can make the regex match account for this edge-case? So we'd have to account for both scenarios of just the exampleVariable and exampleVariableOtherStuffHere......